# how do I find the longest name in an array of objects, then return the entire object to console in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying a few things and was able to return the length of the longest name, but I need to return the entire object in the array. Here is my code:

```js
const instructorWithLongestName = function (instructors) {
  var long1 = 0;
  var arr = instructors;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > long1) {
      long1 = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  return Object.values(long1);
}
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  { name: "Samuel", course: "iOS" },
  { name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web" },
  { name: "Ophilia", course: "Web" },
  { name: "Donald", course: "Web" }
]));
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  { name: "Matthew", course: "Web" },
  { name: "David", course: "iOS" },
  { name: "Domascus", course: "Web" }
]));
```

I would like this to return:

```js
{ name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web" }
{ name: "Domascus", course: "Web" }
```

I tried `long1 = 0` and it just returns `0` for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make two passes: one to get the longest length of an array of instructors, and the other to filter the instructors by longest length.

```js
const instructorWithLongestName = instructors => {
  const longestNameLength = instructors.reduce((longestLength, instructor) => {
    return instructor.name.length > longestLength ? instructor.name.length : longestLength
  }, 0)
  return instructors.filter(instructor => instructor.name.length === longestNameLength)
}

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i].length` doesn't make sense. That is equivalent to doing `{name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"}.length`. length isn't a known property of instructor so it will be null every time.

Use `arr[i].name.length`

```
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  var long1 = 0;
  var maxIndex = 0;
  var arr = instructors;
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i].name.length > long1){
        long1= arr[i].name.length;
        maxIndex= i;
      }
  }
  return instructors[i];
}
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I made the adjustments and it is giving me undefined?

Comment: I made a typo. It should be `return instructors[maxIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accessing the the properties inside your object correctly. There is also no need for `Object.values` you can just save the object you are looking for in a variable return it.

```
      var long1 = 0;
      var longNameObj = {}
      var arr = instructors;
      for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          if (arr[i].name.length > long1){
            long1= arr[i].name.length;
            longNameObj = arr[i]
          }
      }
      return longNameObj
    }
EDIT: fix typo
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback @adam.k. I made the adjustments and am getting empty objects?

Comment: Type for me as well it should be `if (arr[i].name.length)`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
    let max_length_el = instructors[0];
    for(let i=1;i<instructors.length;i++)
    {
    if(instructors[i].name.length>max_length_el.name.length){
        max_length_el = instructors[i];     
    }
  }
  return max_length_el;
}
```

Comment: great, thanks @Satyam Mishra, another great option to work with!